# Codeigniter : How to separate implode results

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, variables

this is about options cart library in codeigniter. 
i have options in product

```
$option = $item['options'];
// result is $option = Array ( [Size] => 33 [color] => brown )
```

I managed to remove or convert an array to a string. result is

```
$option = implode(',', $option);
print_r($option);
// result is $option = 33,brown
```

My question is how to separate the results into something like this.

```
$option_size = 33;
$option_color = brown;
```

Because the result will I put in the array and I will enter into the database.

```
$data_order[] = array(
        'invoice'        => $invoice,
        'nama_produk'    => $item['name_product'],
        'option_size'    => $option_size,
        'option_colour'  => $option_color,
        'qty'            => $item['qty'],
        'price'          => $price,
        'weight'         => $item['weight'],
          );
$this->db->insert_batch('order_product', $data_order);
```

thankyou very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$option = $item['options'];
$option_size = $option['Size'];
$option_color = $option['color'];
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fca6029e0555c12533258364f32adce048a38710)

Comment: glad to help you! Accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem! @DannySetyawan

Comment: oh yeahh. just one problem and maybe you can. 
can you change year 2017 to 17 in php?

Comment: you can use date('y') to get 17 look at this link:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, [**live demo**](https://eval.in/814827).

```
foreach($option as $k => $v)
{
  $key = 'option_' . $k;
  $$key = $v;
}
echo $option_Size;
```

Answer (score 0):

While Alessandro's is probably the most direct (and therefor easiest) way to get the job done the PHP function `extract` is another possibility - [documentation here](http://www.php.net/extract).

The function takes an associative array that treats keys as variable names and values as variable values. For example:

```
$option = Array('Size' => 33, 'color' => brown );
extract($option);
echo "Size: $Size, Color: $color";
```

The above outputs

> Size: 36, Color: brown

You can use the variables `$Size` and `$color` anywhere you need in the scope of  where `extract` is called.